# make : source and binary same name

Tags: makefile

I have many file with extension `.cpp`

```
f001.cpp
abc.cpp
...
```

I try compile any file with this

```
%.cpp:
        g++ -o $* $*.cpp
```

but I get

```
make: *** No hay objetivos.  Alto.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
f001.o:

%.o: %.cpp
        g++ -o $@ $<
```

**EDIT:**

Good! Now try this:

```
OBJETIVOS = f001.o abc.o def.o ghi.o

todos: $(OBJETIVOS)

%.o: %.cpp
        g++ -o $@ $<
```

There is one problem here. Usually `abc` is the executable binary file, and `abc.o` is the object file. You are building executable files, but calling them `abc.o`. If you want them to be executable files, it would be better to call them `abc`.

Comment: with this only compile one file

Comment: for eliminate `.o` : `OBJETIVOS = f001 abc ...`
and `%: %.cpp`

Comment: and for catch all basename of *.cpp I used `$(basename $(shell ls *cpp))`

Answer (score 1):

with the answer of @Beta, I solved with

```
files = $(basename $(shell ls *cpp))                                                     

all: $(files)                                                                            

%: %.cpp                                                                                 
    g++ -o $@ $<                                                                

clean:                                                                                   
    rm $(files)
```

https://gist.github.com/3726212

Comment: You can also use `SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)` and `FILES = $(SOURCES:.cpp=)`.