# makefile to generate multiple executables

Tags: makefile

I want to generate executable from source independents files in a directory. The makefile is:

```
%: %.c
    gcc $< -o $@
```

but this does not work.

This one works (file foo.c exists):

```
foo: foo.c
    gcc $< -o $@
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
files = $(basename $(shell ls *.c))
all: $(files)
%: %.c                                                             
    gcc $< -o $@
```

Source:
[make : source and binary same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433245/make-source-and-binary-same-name)